# Python Facebook graph api - Upload photo to fan page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this http://blog.carduner.net/2011/09/06/easy-facebook-scripting-in-python/ to interface with facebook's graph api via python.

My problem is that I can't seem to upload photos to a fan page. Instead it uploads onto my wall. However, I can post comments fine on the fan page.

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
import imp
urlretrieve('https://raw.github.com/gist/1194123/fbconsole.py', '.fbconsole.py')
fb = imp.load_source('fb', '.fbconsole.py')
fb.AUTH_SCOPE = ['publish_stream', 'manage_pages']
fb.authenticate()

fb.graph_post("/<fan page id>/photos", {"message":"My photo", "source":open("photo.jpeg")})
```

Does anyone else have a problem with upload photos to fan pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the post is appearing on your personal user's wall and not on the page's wall, you are using the wrong access token.  You need to be using a page access token.

You can read more on the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/)

Basically, in order to get that access token, you'll need to provide your application with the `manage_pages` permission.  After that you can make a call to `/me/accounts` and get a list of all the pages that the user administrates.  In that list there should be the access tokens for each page.

I'm not 100% sure how you would set the access token with the library you are using, but essentially all you need to do is append the token to the request with the `access_token` parameter.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/WHATEVER_YOU_ARE_DOING?access_token=XXX
```